ADI and Hf results explanation
I have calculated spectral entropy Hf and ADI as well as BI, NDSI, AEI, ACI for one minute acoustic recordings for ~ two weeks (one week in March and one in April) with the default settings of scikit-maad.
I plot their mean hourly values over a day and try to describe the soundscape accordingly.
But what when Hf is opposite to ADI? Shouldn't acoustic diversity and spectral entropy agree? At this same point I become high BI and high NDSI, so biophony is prevailing , but what else should I take into consideration?
This sample has a strong frequency band 0-1000 Hz, due to wind and sheep bells.

I think the questions posed here might be a bit too general and open-ended for the StackExchange format. The question of "what else should I take into consideration?" sounds like it might be better answered via a formal course on- or literature review of ecoacoustics. Perhaps if you could clarify why you think acoustic diversity and spectral diversity should agree (e.g. provide a reference, provide some data, explain what and where you are recording, or post some data and results) you might be more likely to get a response.

Thanks Brian, I'll review the question and comeback with more details. All the best!
